# Does a homomorphic image of even permutations consist of even permutations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> If $f:S_n \to S_n$ is a homomorphism, prove $f(A_n) \subseteq A_n$.

If every image of a transposition is even, then there is nothing to prove, but it is not sure..

How can I prove the problem?

Comment: Hint: What are the homomorphisms from $S_n$ to $C_2$ (are there any others than the sign?)

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft what is $C_2$?

Comment: cyclic group of two element

Comment: I know the homomorphism, he says. But isn't it not relative to the given homomorphism f?

Comment: $$\;1\lneq N\lhd G\;,\;\;N\lneq G\;\implies \exists\;k\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;G_k\rlap{\;\,/}\subset N $$

Well, take a peek at $\;G_k\cap N\lhd G_k\;$ . By the above, it must be $\;G_k\cap N=1\;$ and etc.

Comment: $$G_1\subseteq G_2\subseteq G_3\subseteq \dots\subseteq G_n \subseteq G_{n+1}\subseteq \cdots$$

Are all simple groups. Prove that $$G=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$$ is also a simple group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- $A_n$ is the set of products of an even number of transpositions

  > *this is one common definition of $A_n$*
- $A_n$ is the set of products of products of two transpositions

  > *just group pairs of transpositions*
- $A_n$ is the set of products of 3-cycles

  > $(12)(23)=(123)$, $(12)(34)=(123)(234)$
- $A_n$ is the set of products of squares

  > $(123)=(132)^2$ *and the square of every permutation is even*
- $f$ maps products of squares to products of squares

  > $f$ *is a homomorphism*
- $f$ maps $A_n$ into $A_n$.

Comment: I've followed an argument from MacLane–Birkhoff *Algebra*, where they prove that $A_n$ is a characteristic subgroup of $S_n$ using that it is generated by squares. Why don't they conclude that $A_n$ is fully invariant as above??

Comment: $A_n$ is the *set* of squares for $n\le 5$. See http://oeis.org/A003483.

Comment: Wow! Your answer is very constructive. Thanks a lot:)