# Prove $H$ is a subgroup of $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H = \{\alpha^2 | \alpha \in S_5\}$.

Prove $H$ is a subgroup of $S_5$.

Any help is appreciated on this proof. I am not sure where to begin. I am comfortable using the two-step subgroup test where you have to show: 
(1) the product of two elements of H is in H and (2) the inverse of an element is in H.

Comment: Note that is not true for $S_n$ in general, only for $n\le 5$. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/538179/589.

Answer (score 0):

For (2): Take an element $\alpha \in H$. According to the Definition of H,  there is a $\beta \in S_5 $ with $ \alpha = \beta^2 $.

Because of ${\beta}^{-1} \in S_5 $, we get: ${\alpha}^{-1} =
 ({\beta}^{2})^{-1} = {\beta}^{-1}{\beta}^{-1} = ({\beta}^{-1})^{2} \in H  $