# $A_n$ is generated by $3$-cycles for $n>2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading about alternating groups and I have seen this theorem :

> For $n> 2$,  $A_n$ is generated by $3$-cycles.

I am confused about it.

Now if we have a group that generated by an element we would have that element multiplied by itself (or whatever binary operations) until we back to the identity.
But in this case the proof of the theorem takes an arbitrary element of the group and write it as decomposition of $3$-cycles .
In a theorem proving that $A_n$ is simple they tried to find a $3$-cycle in a subgroup that assumed to be normal in $A_n$ and once they found it they conclude that the subgroup is equal to $A_n$ hence $A_n$ is simple.

So is it right that any subgroup $H$ of $A_n$ that include a $3$-cycle is trivial i.e $H=A_n$?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/538179/589

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Generated by the three-cycles" means "generated by *all* the three-cycles", not by any one particular three-cycle. That means any even permutation can be written as a product of three-cycles, but not necessarily as the power of some three-cycle. In the same way, the full symmetric group is generated by the two-cycles (the transpositions).

Comment: thank you for your answer, however in the prove of simplicity of A5 it exsactly says in the beginning ( let N be a normal subgroup  of A5 with #N > 1. We will show that N contains a 3-cycle. It follows that N= A5 by the above lemma)

Comment: Once $N$ contains a three-cycle the fact that it's normal implies that it contains all the three-cycles.

Comment: Clear now thank you very much