# How to prove that an even permutation of $A_n$ is a square of another permutation from $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I am trying to go through a proof which contains a statement that an even permutation from $A_n$ is a square of another permutation from $S_n$. My basic ideas are like this:

Suppose an even permutation is $y$. As the signature of an even permutation is $+1$, we are able to write it as a product of $t_{1}t_{2}t_{3}t_{4}...t_{2r-1}t_{2r}$ with each $t$ standing for a two cycle. Then, consider $t_{1}t_{2}$, it can be written as $(ij)(kl)$ if $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ are distinct, or as $(ij)(jk)$ if they are not distinct. However, $(ij)(kl) = (ikjl)^2$ and $(ij)(jk) = (ikj)^2$, which means each of the $t_1t_2$, $t_3t_4$,...,$t_{2r-1}t_{2r}$ is a square of another permutation of $S_n$, say $x_i$.

However, how does it imply that $y$ is a square of another permutation? If $y = x_1^2...x_r^2$, does it necessarily mean that $y$ is a square of something? Is $x_i$ commutative in this case? I need some hints, thanks.

Comment: Aren't all elements $A_n$ even permutations?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/538179/589

Comment: The result claimed is in general not true.  But it is true for n=5

Comment: It's only true for $n\leq 5$, apparently. So in the cases where it's true, it can be computed directly.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. A permutation is the square of another permutation if and only if, its cycle decomposition has an even number of cycles of length $m$ for every even number $m$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wonder is there a strict proof of that? I am not so sured that these cycles are distinct so that I can change the order of them to make a perfect square...For example, if p = x^2y^2 does it mean that p is a square of another permutation?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266569/how-to-find-the-root-of-permutation

Answer (score 1):

Some more hints:

Begin by studying the cycle structures of squares $\sigma:=\pi\circ\pi$ of arbitrary permutations. For this it is sufficient to find out what happens to a cycle of odd length under squaring, and what happens to a cycle of even length under squaring.

Answer (score 1):

That's not remotely true: the density of squares in $S_n$ goes to zero as $n\to +\infty$ (like $\frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$, actually), while your claim would imply that the $\liminf$ of such density is at least $\frac{1}{2}$. Indeed, if we consider 
$$\sigma = (1\,2)(3\,4\,5\,6) \in A_6 $$
this is not the square of anything in $S_6$. A square in $S_6$ has the property that the cycles with a fixed even length appear with an even multiplicity.

Comment: Your last sentence is completely false.  For example the set of squares in any dihedral group form a subgroup, and the set of squares in $S_5$ are in fact $A_5$.

Comment: Not to mention that the squares form a subgroup of *any* group of odd order.

Comment: I deleted the erroneous sentence.