# Are elements in $A_n$ the squares of elements in $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Tt is true that elements in $A_4$ are squares of elements in $S_4$.
Is it true for $A_n$?

Comment: How about $A_5$?

Answer (score 1):

$A_n$ is the *set* of squares for $n\le 5$. See [oeis.org/A003483](https://oeis.org/A003483).

In general, $A_n$  is the set of products of squares, that is, the subgroup generated by the squares.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/538179/589