Show that every element of $A_n$ is a product of the cycles $(1\, 2\, 3), (1\, 2\, 4), \ldots, (1\, 2\, n)$.
Let $A_n = \left\{ \sigma \in S_n \mid \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) = 1 \right\}$ be the set of all even permutations in $S_n$.
Show that every element of $A_n$ is a product of the cycles $(1\, 2\, 3), (1\, 2\, 4), \ldots, (1\, 2\, n)$.

I first tried to solve this by somehow using that any cycle $(a_1 \dots a_k)$ can be written as $(a_1 \ a_k) \dots (a_1 \ a_2)$ and then I could write $(1 \ 2\ n)$ as $(1\ n) \ (1\ 2)$. But I then didn't know how to continue.
In a second try I wanted to start by proving that I could write $(a\ b\ c)$ as a combination of $(1\ 2 \ n)$ but I failed at permutation concerning $1$ and $2$.
If possible, I don't want to prove this by induction.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/538179/589

Ugh, you CAN write any $(a~b~c)$ as a product of $(1~2~n)$, this is just a special case of a special case of $n\le 5$, right?
We have several cases:
$(a ~ b~ c)=(1~2~n)$, trivial.
$(a ~ b~ c)=(2~1~n)$, trivial, just by squaring $(1~2~n)$.
$(a ~ b ~ c)=(1~3~4)$ (or equivalent. By above, $(2~3~4)$ is equivalent to $(1~3~4)$), not that trivial. $(1~3~4)=(1~2~4)(1~2~3)(1~2~3)$
$(a ~ b ~ c)=(3~4~5)$ not trivial. $(3~4~5)=(1~2~3)(1~2~4)(1~2~5)(1~2~3)(1~2~4)$
Now, you got every 3-cycle. You want to make longer cycles, you can do by this way: since the number of even cycles is even number, first make 2-cycles. For each even cycle $(a_1~a_2~\dots ~a_{2k})$, choose all such $(a_1~a_2)$. Then for $(a_1~a_2)(b_1~b_2)=(a_1~b_2~b_1)(a_1~a_2~b_1)$. So for eall even cycles you have a starting 2-cycle. Then perform $(a_1~a_2~\dots ~a_{2n})=(a_1~a_{2n-1}~a_{2n})\dots(a_1~a_3~a_4)(a_1~a_2)$. For odd cycles, $(a_1~a_2~\dots ~a_{2n+1})=(a_1~a_{2n}~a_{2n+1})\dots(a_1~a_4~a_5)(a_1~a_2~a_3)$.
